# Add column in OTRS ticket view

Tags: otrs

When I open a ticket I see a list of prior interactions. 
I would like that list to also include the time spent/reported when the interaction was added.
But how? There are soooo many configuration options!

Regards,

Jeroen Baten

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow Jeroen. Can you show us what you have already tried? The more specific your problem is, the easier it is for us to help you.

Comment: I tried to find in the GUI some sort of option to add fields to the current list view of a single ticket with its list of interactions. No joy there. I opened the sysconfig to find some configuration parameter that would maybe contain a list of fields to be shown on the current list view of a single ticket with its list of interactions. No joy there either. I studied the OTRS Admin HTML page to find a section that would help. No joy there either. Then I waited for some minutes. Then I posted the question here. :-)

Answer (score 0):

if by `list of prior interactions` you mean the article list, then I'm afraid that you can't do that just by config options. You'd need to edit the module and the template.

if not, please add an screenshot or some explanations of what you want and where you want it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I understand. In the end I fixed this by using the REST interface and OTRS6 also sends the TimeUnits spend. So, this way I could get my hands on the data.